# how to set new query params with exits query params (not delete) in nextjs v13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
"use client";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Accordion from "../accordion/accordion";
import {
  useRouter,
  usePathname,
  useSearchParams,
  useParams,
} from "next/navigation";
import { getBrandsRequest } from "../../../APIRequest/brand/brandApi";
import capitalizeFLetter from "../../../utils/capitalizedFirstWord/capitalizedFirstWord";

const Brand = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [allBrand, setAllBrand] = useState([]);
  const newSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    newSearchParams.set("tab", "cami");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let data = await getBrandsRequest();
      setAllBrand(data);
    })();
  }, []);

  let content = (
    <>
      {allBrand?.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="flex items-center gap-x-2" key={index}>
          <label className="dark:text-white sm:text-[14px] flex items-center">
            <input
              className="w-4 sm:w-3 h-4 mr-2 accent-[#ff007f]"
              name={item?.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index + 1)}
              type="checkbox"
              value={item?.name}
            />
            {capitalizeFLetter(item?.name)}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );

  return (
    <div className=" max-w-[275px] px-5 border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow card w-96 bg-base-100 bg-white dark:bg-gray-700">
      <Accordion title={"Brand"} content={content} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Brand;
```

when i click to checkbox run this code:

```
  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    newSearchParams.set("tab", "cami");
  };
```

but this is show me null.

I have to full url with query params like this: http://localhost:3000/store?pageNo=1&perPage=100&searchKeyword=samsung&min=0&max=8000

and i want to: http://localhost:3000/store?pageNo=1&perPage=100&searchKeyword=samsung&min=0&max=8000&tab=cami

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hook to change params (or even replace them).
This is a simple example

```js
export const useQueryParams = () => {
  const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();
  const prevQueryParamsRef = useRef({});

  const filterValues = (values, options) => {
    const newQueryParams = createSearchParams(Object.keys(values).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (
        !Array.isArray(values[curr]) && values[curr]
        || Array.isArray(values[curr]) && values[curr].length > 0
      ) {
        acc[curr] = values[curr];
      }
      return acc;
    }, {}));

    setQueryParams(newQueryParams, {
      ...options,
      ...{
        state: options?.state || window.history.state,
      },
    });
  };

  const out = {};

  queryParams.forEach((v, k) => {
    out[k] = v;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    prevQueryParamsRef.current = out;
  }, [out]);

  return [out, filterValues, prevQueryParamsRef.current];
};
```

Then you can update a single param with code like this

```js
const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useQueryParams();

setQueryParams({
  ...queryParams,
  ...{
    page: 3,
  },
});
```

or, if you want replace all params

```js
const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useQueryParams();

setQueryParams({
  ...queryParams,
  ...{
    page: 3,
  },
}, {replace: true}); // <-- add this
```

Comment: From where to import useSearchParams() and createSearchParams() hooks?

Comment: Just create a file (for example queryParams.js) with the content from the first code block, then import from there

Comment: ReferenceError: createSearchParams is not defined

Comment: Import it
`import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: but  i use nextjs v13.4 then why i to react-router-dom packages?

Comment: Correct, import useSearchParams from `import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'` and adapt it if necessary (or look here https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L983)

For `createSearchParams` it is a thiny wrapper around https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams.

Have a look to function here https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/dom.ts#L76

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params